# Avoid automatic servlet mapping for a Servlet created as a @Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have a servlet to which I need to supply dependencies via autowiring (it's a class from an external library, I cannot change its code). I try to register it as a bean and later register it using programmatic registration (`ServletContextInitializer`). Here is what I have:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyServlet myServlet() {
        return new MyServlet();
    }
}
```

Also, SpringMVC-related autoconfiguration creates a usual `DispatcherServlet` and maps it at `/`.

When I try to start the application, I get the following:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple servlets map to path /: dispatcherServlet[mapped:JAVAX_API:null],myServlet[mapped:JAVAX_API:null]

So it looks like Spring Boot (or Spring itself?) automatically maps the servlet at the default `/`. I would like to avoid the mapping at all as I just need to create the servlet instance; I will register it myself later.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a `ServletRegistrationBean` then you can provide an extra mapping

```
@Bean
public MyServlet myServlet() {
    return new MyServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean myServletRegistration(MyServlet myServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(myServlet,
            "/myservlet/*");
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return registration;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to autowire the `MyServlet` instance. Yes, I can do it manually using `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#autowireBean()` programmatically, but this is a bit ugly. The question was 'is it possible to create a servlet as a usual `@Bean` AND avoid its automatic mapping to `/`?'

Comment: You can inject your `MyServlet` bean into the definition of its registration. I've updated the answer to show how to do that.